# Calling methods dynamically, when controller is changed

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
# in pjax:success callback
@callController = ->
  if window.currentController != (controller = window.getController())
    window.currentController = controller
    window[controller + "_controller"].call()

# part of window.getController()
# return "users", for example
@getController = ->
  window.location.pathname.split("/")[1]

# controller code
@users_controller = ->
  console.log "code from users_controller"
```

How can I write destructor methods for each controller code? E.g. when `users` changed to `posts` I need to execute `@users_controller.destroy()`.

Or show me another solution for this problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the current controller in `currentController` so you can look up the name using the same `window[c + '_controller']` technique that you're already using. Then, just call `destroy` on what you find:

```
@[@currentController + '_controller'].destroy() if(@currentController)
@currentController = controller
@[@currentController + '_controller']()
```

Also note that you don't need the `call` in there since the `@currentController + '_controller'` property will be a function so you can call it directly; and `@` should be `window` in so you can use `@currentController` instead of `window.currentController`.

Comment: I wrote this [code](http://pastebin.com/jrzxY7gw) and try to `window[controller + "_controller"].destroy()` :D

Comment: That code doesn't define a property on `users_controller`, that just defines a local function. You'd have to `@users_controller.destroy = ...` to add a `destroy` function.